# Not able to increase width of Modal from 'reactstrap' in "React JS"

Tags: reactjs

> ```
> export class A extends Component {
>     constructor(props) {
>         super(props)
>
>         this.state = {
>             collapse: false,
>
>             divWidth: {
>                 width: 700,
>             }
>
>         }
>         this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
>
>
>     }
>     toggle() {
>         this.setState(state => ({ collapse: !state.collapse }));
>     }
>
>     render() {
>         const data = [{
>             name: 'Ayaan',
>             age: 26
>         }, {
>             name: 'Ahana',
>             age: 22
>         }]
>         const columns = [{
>             Header: 'Name',
>             accessor: 'name'
>         }, {
>             Header: 'Age',
>             accessor: 'age'
>         }]
>
>         return (
>             <div>
>                 <Button onClick={this.toggle} >
>                     Click Button
>                  </Button>
>                 <Modal isOpen={this.state.collapse} modalClassName={this.state.divWidth}>
>                     <ModalHeader>Welcome</ModalHeader>
>                     <ModalBody>
>                         <div className="form-group">
>                             <div>
>                                 <ReactTable
>                                     data={data}
>                                     columns={columns}
>                                     defaultPageSize={2}
>                                 />
>                             </div>
>                       </div>
>                     </ModalBody>
>                 </Modal>
>             </div>
>         )
>
>     }
> }
> ```

In above code I am not able to increase width of modal(from reactstrap),we can increase width only till 500px. I have added css property in state named divWidth where I am increasing width to 700 but still it does not work.

Comment: When you look at it in the dev console, what does it say the width is? Is it overwritten? Can you manually adjust it there to see if it's being constrained by something else (i.e., the enclosing div above it)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On  component set `size="lg"` or what you need, and it works.

Or you can set an inline style like so:

```
<Modal size="lg" style={{maxWidth: '700px', width: '100%'}}> ... </Modal>
```

**The docs `reactstrap` really bad to explained.**

Comment: @rom you need to add this as answer

Comment: Don't forget everyone, you can also do `size="xl"`.  To achieve greater sizes than this, you have to use a stylesheet imported and on the `Modal` component itself, specifically a property called `contentClassName`.  By writing to a separate file like styles.css and importing it, it will use those styles if the class name is put in `contentClassName`.

Comment: nice!!! worked for me